# I have header file in /usr/include/bpf directory called tracing.h And including it seems to causing problem. I couldn't use it in include w/w-out -I

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, clang, ebpf

I have this header and function defined in it called `long ptr = PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);` so first running command like following assuming my system config will take care of it finding this header file in `/usr/include/bpf/tracing.h`.

but couldn't find the header file

```
 root@this:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ebpf/Linux-exFilter-main/pkg/probe/bpf# clang -O2 -Wall -g -target bpf  -I /usr/include/ -c kprobe_send.c -o kprobe_send.o
```

I also tried with - I and changing `<bpf/tracing.h>` to `"bpf/tracing.h"` not worked either.

I started this inclusion of -I after I was compiling this program and it causing error on compile, I could not understand the error but this is following

```
    clang: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)


@this:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ebpf/Linux-exFilter-main/pkg/probe/bpf# clang -O2 -Wall -g-target bpf -c kprobe_send.c -o kprobe_send.o
clang: error: unknown argument: '-g-target'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'bpf'
root@this:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ebpf/Linux-exFilter-main/pkg/probe/bpf# clang -O2 -Wall -g -target bpf -c kprobe_send.c -o kprobe_send.o
kprobe_send.c:31:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'srand' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        srand(time(NULL));   /* Seed the random number generator. */
        ^
kprobe_send.c:37:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rand' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                int c = randrange(MAX-i);
                        ^
kprobe_send.c:11:22: note: expanded from macro 'randrange'
#define randrange(N) rand() / (RAND_MAX/(N) + 1)
                     ^
kprobe_send.c:51:22: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PT_REGS_PARM2' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        char *ptr =     PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);
                        ^
kprobe_send.c:51:15: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
        char *ptr =     PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);
              ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
kprobe_send.c:61:22: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
        bpf_map_update_elem(fd,&key,&data,BPF_ANY);
                            ^~
Error at line 37: Unsupport signed division for DAG: 0x18aff58: i64 = sdiv 0x18af668, 0x18afe20, kprobe_send.c:37:11Please convert to unsigned div/mod.
fatal error: error in backend: Cannot select: 0x18aff58: i64 = sdiv 0x18af668, 0x18afe20, kprobe_send.c:37:11
  0x18af668: i64 = sra 0x189bcd8, Constant:i64<32>, kprobe_send.c:37:11
    0x189bcd8: i64 = shl 0x189c4f8, Constant:i64<32>, kprobe_send.c:37:11
      0x189c4f8: i64,ch,glue = CopyFromReg 0x189c018, Register:i64 $r0, 0x189c018:1, kprobe_send.c:37:11
        0x189c150: i64 = Register $r0
        0x189c018: ch,glue = callseq_end 0x189bc08, TargetConstant:i64<0>, TargetConstant:i64<0>, 0x189bc08:1, kprobe_send.c:37:11
          0x189bfb0: i64 = TargetConstant<0>
          0x189bfb0: i64 = TargetConstant<0>
```

What the above error even means, I thought it was complaining I did not include any headers so I started including tracing.h to cater to `PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx)`

How can I get rid of this error?

On this line it says unsupported sign division:

```
Error at line 37: Unsupport signed division for DAG: 0x18aff58: i64 = sdiv 0x18af668, 0x18afe20, kprobe_send.c:37:11Please convert to unsigned div/mod.
```

Is this line 37 referring to assembly or my source file? In line 37 of source file I am doing

```
    int c = randrange(MAX-i);
```

Why is the above simple line is not allowed in ebpf program? This is my line 37 and rest of the bpf program

```
#include <linux/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include <time.h>
//#include <bpf/tracing.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define RAND_MAX 0x7fff
#define PERF_SAMPLE_RAW  1U << 0
#define randrange(N) rand() / (RAND_MAX/(N) + 1)
#define MAX 100000000        /* Values will be in the range (1 .. MAX) */


struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERF_EVENT_ARRAY);
    __uint(key_size, sizeof(int));
    __uint(value_size, sizeof(int));
    __uint(max_entries, 100);
} my_map SEC(".maps");

SEC("kprobe/__x64_sys_recvfrom")
int bpf_prog1(struct pt_regs *ctx,int fd, const char *buf, size_t count)
{

    static int vektor[100000000];
    int candidates[MAX];
    int i;
    long key;

    srand(time(NULL));   /* Seed the random number generator. */

    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    candidates[i] = i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX-1; i++) {
        int c = randrange(MAX-i);
        int t = candidates[i];
        candidates[i] = candidates[i+c];
        candidates[i+c] = t;
    
    }
    
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    vektor[i] = candidates[i] + 1;
    struct S {
        int pid;
        char cookie[90];
        char *ptr;
    } data={1,""};
        char *ptr =     PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);

    //data.pid =count;// bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    //if(buf==NULL)
    //memcpy(data.cookie,buf,20);
    data.ptr=ptr;   
 //     data.cookie[0]=buf[0];
    //bpf_get_current_comm(&data.cookie, sizeof(data.cookie));

    key=vektor[i];
    bpf_map_update_elem(fd,&key,&data,BPF_ANY);
    //bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &my_map, 1, &data, sizeof(data));
    
    return 0;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
int _version SEC("version") = 99;
```

is there any info source where it says what's allowed or what's not allowed because seems to me its just picking arbitrarily what's allowed and what's not looking into ebpf

My kernel: 5.14.1
My clang: 12

libbpf installed but I'd love to find a command that tells its version and or just where it's installed.

On some link I found it says maybe/or definitely (couldn't tell the difference) be a problem of symlink on Ubuntu exact source .. what this even means does it mean I installed libbpf or something and unbuntu messed up with my symlink that help find libbpf headers? How can I understand what this link says? https://github.com/iovisor/kubectl-trace/issues/76#issuecomment-513587108

Comment: Where are the [`srand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) and [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) funcitons declared? In which header file? And where is the `PT_REGS_PARM2` macro define (if anywhere)?

Comment: And check your arguments you pass to the compiler. To be honest, together with your previous questions you seem to be way over your head and trying to do something you're not really ready for. You seem to be missing some of the very basics needed to advanced and non-trivial programming. I would guess you have fallen into [the cargo cult trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) where you find code and commands that you use without really bothering to learn what it does, or possibly try to learn by guessing which will never work well.

Comment: PT_REGS_PARM2 DEFINED I  tracing.h that's include in -I in bpf directory

Comment: Clang -target bpf" is used to compile against libbpf and all bpf supported binaries. So the with -c and         
   "-o"used in compilation and linking.// -c specifically for compiling and "-o" specifically for linking. Is this assumption correct? Or am I just misled by my question command

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can u please see my last comment